# Issue with server running slow on odoo

Tags: server, odoo, pgadmin

Can it be possible that the conversation icon on odoo can make the system run slow. The conversation icon was loading fast before I migrated a bunch of data to the res.partner table. Now the conversation icon loads forever and in return the system becomes slow. I'm guessing the icon is searching for users inside the system, since they're a lot of users, it takes too much time to return. I may be wrong but is it possible that the icon could be the one causing the system to be slow.

Comment: So, what have you tried for yourself? Disabling conversation for example? Removing lots of users and retesting? Etc. It could basically still be a number of things slowing down your instance.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by changing all users to portal then I gradually changed to internal based on the access rights given. The server is working fine and conversation icon returns results real quick. Thanks for your willingness to help

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out. Perhaps its a good idea to answer your own question. Helps with the search history over time.